# on Murray-von Neumann equivalence of range projections

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra and $a\in A$. Then for the range projections $[a]\sim [a^\ast]$, since when $a=v|a|$ is the polar decomposition $v^\ast v$ is the projection onto $ran(v^\ast)=ker(v)^\bot=ker(a)^\bot=ran(a^\ast)$.

Apparently $vv^\ast$ is supposed to be the range projection of $a$, but how do I see this?

Thanks in advance!

---

Soultion: Now, in the view of daylight, I think my admittedly ridiculous problem was the following:

It is known (without having any further knowledge on the polar decomposition of $a^*$ that $vv^*$ is the orthogonal projection onto $ran\ v$ and that this is in fact:
$ran\ v = (ker\ v^*)^\bot \stackrel{!}{=} (ker\ a^*)^\bot = ran\ a^*$, beacause we also know from the polar decomposition of $a$, that $ran\ a =ran\ v$, which in turn implies : $(ran\ a)^\bot=(ran\ v)^\bot$ and $ker\ a^* = ker\ v^*$.

My brain was too stubborn to think that the indicated equation might be as easy as it is and is not due to knowing anything about the polar decomposition of $a^*$.

Thank you @Martin Argerami for your patience nevertheless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 
$$
\operatorname{ran} vv^*=(\ker vv^*)^\perp=(\ker v^*)^\perp=\overline{\operatorname{ran} a}.
$$
For the middle equality, it is true in general that $\ker x^*x=\ker x$. The inclusion $\ker x\subset\ker x^*x$ is trivial. The converse is easily seen if $x\in B(H)$: in that case, if $x^*x\xi=0$, then 
$$
0=\langle x^*x\xi,\xi\rangle=\langle x\xi,x\xi\rangle=\|x\xi\|^2. 
$$

Comment: Thanks, but I got the feeling I'm struggling more with the last equation:

Why is the kernel of $ker\ v^* = ker\ a^*$, i.e. how much of the polar decomposition of the adjoint do I know from the polar decomposition of the operator itself?

Comment: Not sure what you expect. In the proof above replace $a$ with $a^*$ and $v$ with $v^*$, and use $\overline{\operatorname{ran} a^*}=(\ker a)^\perp$ that you already established in your question.

Comment: is $|a|=|a^*|$?, it looks convincing, but $|a|=(a^*a)^{1/2}$ and $|a^*|=(aa^*)^{1/2}$ but then? $a$ needn't be normal, right?

Comment: No, they are not equal, unless $a$ is normal.

Comment: so , does $a^*=v^*|a^*|$ hold then? And if so : why is this? As |a| is hermitian this clearly could not come from anti multiplicity of the involution, otherwise I would not know why the kernels of $a^*$ and $v^*$ should coincide

Comment: The relation is $|a^*|=v|a|v^*$. At this stage, I  have no idea what your question is.